# How to trigger another function on builder.CardAction.openURL() after opening the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I am having trouble using the node.js botframework from Microsoft.

Basically, I want to create an openURL() card such that when the user click on the button, other than opening the URL in a browser, it also triggers another function.

For example in my case, once the button on the openURL() card is clicked, the URL will open **and a series of session.send() will be triggered to occur.**

I tried using the *builder.CardAction.dialogAction()* and *bot.beginDialogAction()* together, but I realised that I cannot open an URL without an interaction from the user, in the new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using the builder.CardAction.dialogAction() and bot.beginDialogAction() together, but I realised that I cannot open an URL without an interaction from the user, in the new function.

You're right to use `builder.CardAction.dialogAction` and `bot.beginDialogAction` here, then to avoid interaction with user to open the url, we can send the url address as parameter to the new dialog, for example:

```
var opn = require('opn');

//other relative codes...

bot.dialog('showCard', (session)=>{
    var msg = new builder.Message(session);
    msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
    msg.attachments([
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title("Test 1")
            .subtitle("This is test 1.")
            .text("this is test 1.")
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "openUrl", "http://www.google.com", "Test 1")
            ]),
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title("Test 2")
            .subtitle("This is test 2.")
            .text("this is test 2.")
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "openUrl", "http://www.bing.com", "Test 2")
            ])
    ]);
    session.send(msg).endDialog();
}).triggerAction({
    matches: /^show card$/i
});

bot.beginDialogAction('openUrl','/openUrl');
bot.dialog('/openUrl',(session, args)=>{
    //your custom action goes here
    session.send("get here");    
    //open the url, I used opn package here.
    opn(args.data);
    session.endDialog();
});
```

As you can see, you may pass the url as parameter here so will the called dialog directly manage to open it with browser.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the node module opn as described in your code. It works when I run it on my pc's bot-emulator but when it was deployed onto Facebook Messenger, it does not open the link but skipped to the next session.send(). Is there any way around this?

Comment: @ChrisHo, I'm not able to test on fb channel, but could you please check if use `builder.CardAction.openUrl` directly, the url will be opened successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Unfortunately when I replaced opn(args.data); with builder.CardAction.openURL(session, args.data); the URL doesn't seem to open. Does builder.CardAction.openURL have to be attached to a card.buttons? If so, I don't think it will work as the user have to click on another button to open the URL.

Comment: @ChrisHo, no, the `builder.CardAction.openUrl` is the built-in method to open url which is used in `HeroCard`, the intent to test so is to exclude the channel issue.

Comment: @ChrisHo, then if this `builder.CardAction.openUrl` still doesn't work in fb channel, I will need to report and check if this is a channel issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do this directly within the Bot Framework SDK purely, but you can use a nodejs package OpenURL to achieve something like this.

First, you'll need to include your packages:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var ourl = require('openurl');
// other packages as necessary
```

Then, you'll need to set up your action:

```
// Set up the button we'll be putting on a card.
// This could be within another dialog, for example.
let urlButton = builder.CardAction
.dialogAction(session, "test", "something", "Test a URL");

let urlCard = new builder.HeroCard(session)
.text("Opens an URL")
.title("Demo")
.buttons([urlButton]);
let msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(urlCard.toAttachment());
session.send(msg);
```

And then you would, in this example, need a couple dialogs set up.  At least, this is how I did it:

```
let someMessages = (session) => {
    session.send("This is one message.");
    session.send("This is another message.");
    session.send("A third message, to be sure..");
};

let openUrlDialog = bot.dialog("openSomeUrl", [
    (session) => {
        // A console message.
        console.log("Fingers crossed!!!");

        // Use OpenURL to open the desired url.
        ourl.open("https://www.microsoft.com");

        // Let's send our messages.
        someMessages(session);

        // End the dialog.
        session.endDialog("This concludes the URL opening and messages test.");
    }
]).triggerAction({matches: /test/gi});

let allElse = bot.dialog("/", (session, args) => {
    if (session.message.text === "action?test=something") {
        session.beginDialog("openSomeUrl");
        return;
    } 

    console.log("Default Dialog");
    session.endDialog("Default Dialog was processed.  Doublecheck.");
}, true); // replace itself in case default was already declared.
```

(Replace `let`s with `var`s and the lambda syntax with functions if not using ES6+).